# Multithreading and error handling in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This Question has 2 parts. I am new to multithreading and so I want to firstly check if my logic is correct and then I want to find out how to handel erros in multithreading.
Q1: I have an application that calls SQL database obtaining information from 2 datatables, this info is then combined in a final display. Without multithreading, I call each SQL select to populate a dataset one after the other. With multithreading I call the more complex SQL first as a separate thread and then the less complex SQL call in the main thread second. I am trying to cut down the load time of both by doing them concurently.
(I realise that strictly I should do both as backround tasks to free up the UI, for me its small steps first) 
Anyway the code looks little like this

```
 Dim ThreadLoad_Longer_Data As Thread
    ThreadLoad_Longer_Data = New Thread(AddressOf Me.Fill_LongerSQL)

        ThreadLoad_Longer_Data.IsBackground = True
        TThreadLoad_Longer_Data.Start()

   'Execute some code here for the second SQL call in main thread

   'Then stop the main prosess to wait for the finish of the of the background
        ThreadLoad_Longer_Data.join
```

Im assuming that the .Join statment will infact stop the main thread and will wait for the other one to finish ? Is this correct ?
If so it brings me to the second part.
Q2. What happens if the first thread dosent finish? Like through an error ? How do I handle this situation ?

Thank you

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker instead, move the code after the Join() to the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, calling `ThreadLoad_Longer_Data.Join` will stop the execution of the calling thread (the one that executes the code calling the Join) till the ThreadLoad_Longer_Data ends its execution.

If, inside ThreadLoad_Longer_Data, you have an unhandled exeception, the result is the ending of the thread and thus the resume of the execution of the calling thread.

```
Sub Main
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Start of the main thread")
        Dim ThreadLoad_Longer_Data As Thread 
        ThreadLoad_Longer_Data = New Thread(AddressOf Me.Fill_LongerSQL) 
        ThreadLoad_Longer_Data.IsBackground = True 
        ThreadLoad_Longer_Data.Start() 
        ThreadLoad_Longer_Data.Join
        Console.WriteLine("End of the main thread")
    Catch x as Exception
      Console.WriteLine(x.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub Fill_LongerSQL()
    Console.WriteLine("Before the exception")
    dim y as integer
    for x = 0 to 1000000000
        y = y + 1
    next
    Throw new Exception("This is an unhandled exception")
    ' this will never executed
    Console.WriteLine("After the exception")
End Sub
```